# How to read attribute of a parent node from a child node in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

Just want to know how to read an attribute of a parent node from a child node in XSLT.
code:

```
<A>
  <b attr1="xx">
    <c>
    </c>
  </b>
</A>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="c">
  <xsl:value-of select="attribute of b node">
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can go "up" a level using "`..`". So:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@attr1"/>
```

Comment: yeah just now coded //@attr1  and it worked for me...anyways thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Wondering - the expression "//@attr1" will scan the ENTIRE document (and won't stop even when it finds the first match).  This is very inefficient and could grab the wrong @attr1(if you have that attribute in other places).  @Adam Batkin's solution is more efficient and less likely to accidentally select the wrong value.

Comment: @Mads: Thanks for ur inputs and information,will implement the same